# How can I use Material-UI Autocomplete together with virtua?

Tags: material-ui

There are a few examples of using Material-UI Autocomplete with list virtualization libraries. MUI employs the react-window library for one of its [examples](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#virtualization), although it's important to note that this approach requires knowledge of item heights, which can be a bit cumbersome.

We are contemplating a switch to a more modern library. Is there a functional example available that demonstrates the integration of the [Virtua library](https://github.com/inokawa/virtua) with MUI's autocomplete virtualization?

Comment: I doubt that there are any. Have you tried it yourself? If yes, what issues did you face?